# Regular expressions split and match

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> zznew
'...0002211 118 7.5 "Weeds" (2005) {The Love Circle Overlap (#4.10)}'

>>> re.split('\(+\d+\)',zznew)
['...0002211 118 7.5 "Weeds" ', ' {The Love Circle Overlap (#4.10)}']

>>> m = re.match('\(+\d+\)',zznew)

>>> m.groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#104>", line 1, in <module>
    m.groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

in the above example when i use split it matches with (2005) and splits it...
but when i use match its not match...the m.groups() file is empty..
what is wrong with this :(

Comment: Is it intentional that your regular expression matches multiple open parentheses, for example '((((2005)'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`re.search`**](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [**`re.match`**](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match).

The difference between these two methods is that `re.match` only matches if the match starts at the beginning of the string, whereas `re.search` can match anywhere in the string. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching) for more details.

As [NullUserException](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) points out, if you want to extract the year you can do it as follows:

```
m = re.search('\((\d+)\)', zznew)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you are planning on extracting the year from it, use `\\((\d+)\\)` instead.

Comment: @ullUserException: Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer accordingly.